# Distinguish between multiple USB Microphones with JMF

Tags: java, javasound, jmf

Is there a way to distinguish between multiple USB microphones with JMF. Currently each USB Mic interfaces with the generic USB windows driver and registers with JMF as a "DirectSound" capture.  Problem is when I talk out of either Mic they both get picked up by JMF. I want only want Mic to be used.

I can use JavaSound to distinguish between the two but I have already built system using JMF.

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Can you use the information gained from Java Sound in the JMF app.?

Comment: I have been trying. I am not sure where the connection is. If I could create a new DataSource or MediaLocator from JavaSound it would convert easily into JMF.